# How to compile Google Go bin with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I have started to learn Go and I have installed Go plugin on IntelliJ I have compiled and run sucessful some really simple code pieces. However I don't find any bin file in the bin folder, and the compiler runs this command to execute the app

```
C:/Go/bin/go.exe run E:/IntelliJ/untitled/src/myApp.go
```

How to get the binary of my compiled code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `go build`, `go run` simply creates a temporary file somewhere and executes it then deletes it.

Comment: I have tried to go in the menu `Build-> Make Project` the compilation seems start and complete successfull but I don't find any binary. Can I create a  .exe or whatever bin from IntelliJ?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) the plugin you're using? maybe try one of the nightly builds down on their github page.

Comment: Yes I use this plugin. Unfortunately there is't a great IDE support actually, I hope in a future official Jetbrains support to this language. But seems pretty strange that I cannot find any binary since I can compile and run. actually what IDE(or editor) do you use?

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 + [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime), I used to use IntelliJ but ST3 + GoSublime blew it away.

Comment: You can use one of the alpha/nightly builds and use the 'Go application' runner to get the binary as well. If you want to give more details (plugin version) I can definitely help you out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify *output* dir in your run/debug configuration like

**E:\IntelliJ\untitled\.idea\output**